# Como aislar bootstrap y mis estilos para que no interfieran con otro proyecto

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, webpack, sass

He construido una libreria JS que renderiza vistas usando metodos. El problema es que he utilizado bootstrap para la UI y cuando alguien importa la libreria mi bootstrap hace conflictos con el css del proyecto que lo importa.

Utilizo webpack he importo bootstrap de esta manera:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import 'custom-css';

.font-awesome {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

He probado hacer el import dentro de un id en plan:

```
    #id {
      @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
    }
```

pero no funciona.

Así importo mi CSS al proyecto, directamente al entrypoint que luego coje webpack para buildear.

```
import './styles/application.scss';
```

Y mi configuracion de webpack es asi:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: ['style-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
    },
    {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'style-loader',
          options: {
            esModule: true,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
        },
        'sass-loader',
      ],
    },
```

Y cabe destacar que no estoy usando las clases asi:

```
<div class="${style.myClass}"/>
```

Las utilizo de forma clasica:

```
<div class="myClass"/>
```